# I currently have some VBA code that runs and highlights cells based on their contents. How do I add VBA to check column R if the cells are blank?

Tags: colors, cell

This is what I currently, have, and it works great! I'm unsure how to add the other option for blank cells in column R.

```
Sub Highlight_Specials()
'
' Highlight_Specials Macro
'
'
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""RAND"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
Columns("P:P").Select
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
    Formula1:="=""YES"""
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
    .Color = -16383844
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 13551615
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-9
End Sub
```

I'm certainly no expert, but I was able to edit the VBA above to find specific words in my spreadsheet and highlight them. "RAND" as well as "Yes" are highlighted properly....Just how do I specify a blank cell that is still in the body of the data? (I don't want it to highlight every other cell on the spreadsheet!)

Any help or suggestions on what to read, would be appreciated!